# Status bar and toolbar goes from transparent to opaque on scroll like in Letterboxd

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar, statusbar, transparent

I've been trying to find ways to replicate this behavior from Letterboxd where status bar and toolbar goes from transparent to opaque once the scroll hit movie title: [demo](https://youtu.be/FA9DL6DEG1Q)

The closest I find is using collapsing toolbar with CoordinatorLayout or more recent MotionLayout. But I think that's more elaborate than what it actually needs. So, what do I do?